# Ошибка на learn js? Или моя невнимательность?)

Tags: javascript

user1 у меня выводит `{name: '', age: 30}`
user1 выводит `{name: 'name', age: 30}`
Но, в learn js написанно, что записи аналогичные, значит и результат должен быть один и то же.

```
   let user1 = {
      name,
      age: 30,
    };
    
    let user2 = {
      name: 'name', 
      age: 30,
    };
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, переменная `name` должна быть объявлена в текущей области видимости. Во-вторых, на Learn JS нет кавычек во втором примере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const name = 'John';
let user1 = {
  name,
  age: 30,
};

let user2 = {
  name: name,
  age: 30,
};

console.log(user1, user2);
```